# optimize time problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John and Tom are going to finish two projects $P_1, P_2$.

If John want to accomplish the two projects by himself,  it will cost him $10$ days, $15$ days to  finish $P_1, P_2$, respectively.

If Tom want to accomplish the two projects by himself,  it will take him $8$ days, $20$ days to  finish $P_1, P_2$, respectively.

John and Tom  Can collaborate work together on these projects.  How many days will it take to   accomplish the two projects  **at least**?

I think, the first $8$ days, John and Tom  work on  $P_2, P_1$, respectively;  the following $4$ days, John and Tom collaborate work on  $P_1$, so the answer is $12$ days.

But, we need a **proof**. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might have completely misinterpreted the problem, and if I did, say so in the comments, and I will delete this answer.

EDIT: I did. Here is a revised answer.

First, it is clear that the best use of Tom's time is through working on P1. This is obvious. Therefore, he should spend the entire time working on P1 until it has finished. However, after this, the question is what John's best course of action is.

If Tom's most efficient use of time is through P1, any work John does on P1 will decrease the amount of time Tom can use his epic 1/8 project per day P2. In other words, any work John does on P1 will just mean less time Tom can work on P1, his best task. Therefore, to optimize the amount of time Tom can spend on P1, John should start on P2 and continue until one of them finishes.

8 days later, Tom finishes. The only logical course of action would be to help John finish P2, as it is the only task left.

Comment: your understanding is right, but the answer.....

Comment: I might have been under the false assumption that they have to do the projects in order and can only move on once they have both completed the first project.